# Want to capture fields which get updated in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I wish to create a generic component which can save the Object Name and field Names with old and new values in a BigObject. 
The brute force algo says, on every update of each object, get field API names using describe and check old and new value of those fields. If it gets modified insert it into new BigObject.
But it will consume a lot of CPU time and I am looking for an optimum solution to handle this.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, do you have any code written already? Maybe benchmark it and then see what you can optimise instead of overdesigning it from the start... Keep it simple, write test harness and then try to optimise (without breaking unit tests).

Couple random ideas:

- You'd be doing that in a trigger? So your "describe" could happen only once. You don't need to describe every single field, you need only one operation outside of trigger's main loop.

  `Set<String> fieldNames = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keyset();
  System.debug(fieldNames);`

  This will get you "only" field names but that's enough. You don't care whether they're picklists or dates or what. Use that with generic `sObject.get('fieldNameHere')` and it's a good start.
- or maybe without describe at all. sObject's [`getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) will give you cool Map which you can easily iterate & compare.
- or `JSON.serialize` the old & new version of the object and if they aren't identical - you know what to do. No idea if they'll always serialise with same field order though so checking if the maps are identical might be better
- do you really need to hand-craft this field history tracking like that? You have 1M records free storage but it could explode really easily in busier SF org. Especially if you have workflows, processes, other triggers that would translate to multiple updates (= multiple trigger runs) in same transaction. Perhaps normal field history tracking + chatter feed tracking + even salesforce shield (it comes with 60 more fields tracked I think) would be more sensible for your business needs.